# Find the possible eigenvalues for the given equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the eigenvalues of $A$, given that

$$aA^3 -bA^2+cA-dI_{n} = O_{n\times n}$$

where $O_{n\times n}$ is the zero $n$ x $n$ matrix and $a, b, c, d$ are constants.

I've generalised the above with constants, so that if I have the method I can try to work out the actual eigenvalues.

From the above, I know that eigenvalues can be derived from:

$$a{\lambda}^3 -b{\lambda}^2+c{\lambda}-d$$

But this is where I am stuck at. I've tried factorising the above, but not sure what to equate it to.

So far in class, we have just began finding eigenvalues (and eigenvectors) from matrices.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The eigenvalues of $A$ satisfy $a{\lambda}^3 -b{\lambda}^2+c{\lambda}-d=0.$

Comment: @mfl Thank you for the quick reply! I've got the cubic equation, and I've tried factorising it, which brings me onto the question, can eigenvalues, ${\lambda}$, be complex?

Comment: I don't see any reason to discard that possibility. If I am not wrong you can consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}3 & -2 \\ 4 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and get the adequate $a,b,c,d.$ The eigenvalues of $A$ are complex: $1\pm 2i.$

Comment: @mfl Ah nice! So the values of a, b, c, and d from your matrix A, are 3, -2, 4, and 1 respectively? If not, how have you derived the values of a, b, c and d from that matrix? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: No. Take, for example, $a=1,b=2,c=5,d=0.$ I have obtained them using wxMaxima.